# My <a> not working and neither is the hover property

Tags: html, css

So I made this top menu with divs because the guy wants boxes and wants them all the exact same size regardless of the text.  It looks fine but will not activate the  property or the hover. Please help.

The css is

```
.headerbottomcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 980px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height: 78px;
    border: 1px dotted #27c3ed;
}

.headerbottomleft {
    width: 290px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border: 1px dotted #F36;
    min-height: 66px;
}

.headerbottomright {
    width: 640px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    min-height: 66px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px dotted #27c3ed;
}


.headerbottomrighttop {
    height: 28px;  /*Change to 30 when remove borders*/
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px dotted #093;
}

.headerbottomrightbottom {
    height: 28px;  /*Change to 30 when remove borders*/
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px dotted #C60;
    }

.navbuttonfirst {
    width: 122px;
    height: 16px; /*Change to 30 when remove borders*/
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    float: left;    
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    border-radius: 3px;

}

.navbutton {
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 122px;
    height: 16px; /*Change to 30 when remove borders*/
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    float: left;    
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.navbutton:hover{
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

And the HTML IS

```
    <div class="headerbottomcontainer">
        <div class="headerbottomleft">
        </div>

        <div class="headerbottomright">
            <div class="headerbottomrighttop">

                <div class="navbuttonfirst">
                    <a href="http://www.jetnightclub.com/events.html">Events</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbutton">
                <a href="photos.html">Photos</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbutton">
                    <a href="videos.html">Videos</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbutton">
                    <a href="ourclub.html">Club Info</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbutton">
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="headerbottomrightbottom">
                <div class="navbuttonfirst">
                    <a href="birthdays.html">Birthdays</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbutton">
                    <a href="barhop.html">Bar Hop</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbutton">
                    <a href="newyears2013-2014.html">New Year's</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbutton">
                    In the mix
                </div>
                <div class="navbutton">
                    Downloads
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see `:hover` anywhere in your CSS, also for this purpose consider using `ul` and `li` elements nested under `nav`

Comment: add :hover in your navbutton .navbutton:hover
{
 background-color: #333333;
 color: #006633;
}

Comment: Yeah i took the hover out cause it wasnt working sorry will add it back.....still doesnt work....any idea why my <a> doesnt work/

Comment: @user3098121 : use your <a> link tag inside the div like this  <div class="navbutton"><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></div> and then in your css .navbutton a:hover{color: #000000;}. it will work. As alien said use ul and li for navigation bar...

Comment: @indian I changed the links so they are inside the div. I will try and redo with ul and li no problem. but the hover and links more importantly do not work...I am so frustrated....

Comment: just post your code in jsfiddle

Comment: whats jsfiddle? @indian are u interested in looking at it for me? can transfer money through paypal

Comment: i think you missed this one. add .navbutton a:hover{color: #000000;}.

Comment: @indian ok i can do that but the links dont even work. that is my main concern rather than the hover

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ go to this site and post your html and css code in appropriate place..

Comment: specify a in your .navbutton a:hover. did you noticed that a?

Comment: i will do that but before worrying about the styling of the hover....I just want the links to work. you can check out the site at www.jetnightclub.com/index.html you need the index or else it redirects...

Comment: I ut it in jfiddle and the hover and the links work....doesnt display properly due to images and external style sheets but the links and hover work....on the website doesnt work.......UGHHh lol

Comment: first try this code in separate .html file and then integrate into your full website page coding.

Comment: I did and it works. but on the website it doesnt work and im not sure why.........could u check it out? like i said im willing to pay $$

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsfiddle/info jsfiddle is a online ide.

Comment: but here in andaman islands internet is very slow. still i didn't see your index page www.jetnightclub.com/index.html ok wait i will check it for u..

Comment: ok thanks a million. like i said I am willing to send a little holiday gift :):) if you PM me your paypal.

Comment: now is this works on your live site or not?

Comment: no it is not working at all....:( even the links (whichis the most important) dont work..

Comment: may be you have some error or invalid codes in other area i think..

Comment: @indian not interested in debugging are u?

Comment: i'm always interested to clear bugs. but here internet is very slow..

Comment: are u willing to do it? like i said i am willing to pay. I have 8 hours :D

Comment: @user3098121 : what have you done? you did same mistake here man.. i checked your style.css file. you didn't add the code properly this is wrong ->.navbutton:hover{background-color:#f00;} this is correct ->.navbutton a:hover{background-color:#f00;}

Comment: @indian like I said I am not worried right now about the hover. I understand the error there. My problem is that the links dont even work....thats the issue i need to solve.

Comment: which links? photo, videos, club info.. huh

Comment: yup the 10 in the header bar there

Comment: add your url links properly like this -> href="http://www.jetnightclub.com/photos.html" not like this <a href="photos.html">Photos</a>

Comment: @indian yup just did that and no difference. had tried on one link before and no difference....

Comment: is that url links are working in your localhost or not?

Comment: @indian no none of the links in the bottom bar part work

Comment: but here its working fine in my localhost

Comment: with the linked css sheets and everything? with the whole page? the index page? I am so discouraged......

Comment: @indian when u type in the url online it works too? not sure what u mean by local host to be hones.t..

Comment: url links are not working or that url link names are does not show in the menu bar? which one is problem?

Comment: @indian the names show......but when i put my mous/click nothign happens and there does not appear to be a url there

Comment: no. first apply your 10 href links properly as i said above. it should work. this is the right way...really this is weirdest problem..

Comment: I did apply the links properly like u said.....i just didnt update my post but if u check the source code they are http://www......

Comment: @indian any other ideas?

Comment: you have some another element which is overlap your nav bar...

Comment: @Indian OMFG that was it. I have no clue why i didnt think of that. Ughhhh maybe cause its 3AM here lol. PLEASE SEND ME YOUR PAYPAL ADDRESS SO I CAN SEND A TOKEN OF APPRECIATION. Thanks so much.

Comment: is that working now or not?

Comment: @indian yes it is thank you so much. Like i said please PM your paypal address. Thanks a million

Comment: now did you got result what you want?i want to talk to you privately. could you please..

Comment: @indian yes no problem how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try

.navbutton:hover{
    background-color:#FF0000;
}

.navbuttonfirst:hover{
    background-color:#FF0000;
}

Put the  inside  i.e.   ...
You have to add hover effect for   like this. Forgive my color selection.

Comment: thank you i know that part but for some reason doesnt work on the live site

Answer (score 0):

Can you add `a:hover` or for specific class`.classname:hover`

```
 a:hover{

     color:red; 
 }
```

CSS for unvisited, visited, hover, and active links,

```
a:link    {color:green;}
a:visited {color:green;}
a:hover   {color:red;}
a:active  {color:yellow;}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know that part but for some reason it doesnt work on the live site..

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code..

```
.navbuttonfirst a {
    width: 122px;
    height: 16px; /*Change to 30 when remove borders*/
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    float: left;    
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    border-radius: 3px;

}

.navbutton a{
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 122px;
    height: 16px; /*Change to 30 when remove borders*/
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    float: left;    
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.navbutton a:hover{
    background-color:#f00;
}
```